# Call Prototype's Method from Inheriting Object's Function

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm trying to understand JavaScript's prototypical inheritance. In the following code snippet, I attempt to call a function from within an inheriting object's function with the same name. (Essentially, I'm trying to mimic calling a "super" method).

```
function Base() {

}
Base.prototype.hello = function() {
    return "hello";
}

function Sub() {
    Base.call(this);
}
Sub.prototype.hello = function() {
    return this.prototype.hello() + " world";
}
Sub.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
Sub.prototype.constructor = Sub;

var sub = new Sub();
alert(sub.hello());
```

The result is not what I expected... `sub.hello()` returns `"hello"`, but I expected it to return `"hello world"`. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are setting a hello property on the `Sub` prototype, but the prototype is overriden by `Object.create` on the next line.

```
Sub.prototype.hello = function() {
    return this.prototype.hello() + " world";
}
Sub.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
```

Switch the order of those statements, and use a reference to `Base` in the `Sub` `hello` method. The code should look like this:

```
function Base() {
}
Base.prototype.hello = function() {
    return "hello";
}

function Sub() {
    Base.call(this);
}
Sub.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
Sub.prototype.hello = function() {
    return Base.prototype.hello() + " world";
}
Sub.prototype.constructor = Sub;

var sub = new Sub();
console.log(sub.hello()); // "hello world"
```